# Mapbox legend works on desktop, tablet, but not on mobile. How do I fix it to display correctly on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In developer tools for Chrome, the legend displays perfectly on top of a mapbox map for desktop, tablet and mobile.  Here is what is looks like.  It displays a semitransparent horizontal legend.

[image]

If I actually use my iPhone though, the legends displays incorrectly.  It becomes vertical and all formatting appears lost.

[image]

Here is my mapbox control:

```
 // Control implemented as ES6 class
    class fs_legend_control {

        onAdd(map) {
        var fs_legend_control_html = ' \
        <div class="my-legend"> \
            <div class="legend-title">Piste Difficulty Legend</div> \
                <div class="legend-scale"> \
                    <ul class="legend-labels"> \
                        <li><span style="background:#339933;"></span>Novice</li> \
                        <li><span style="background:#097CCB;"></span>Easy</li> \
                        <li><span style="background:#ED151F;"></span>Intermed\'</li> \
                        <li><span style="background:#000000;"></span>Advanced</li> \
                        <li><span style="background:#ffa502;"></span>Expert</li> \
                        <li><span style="background:#ffff01;"></span>Freeride</li> \
                        <li><span style="background:#ffc0cb;"></span>Unrated</li> \
                    </ul> \
                </div> \
            <div class="legend-source"> <a href="https://www.example.com/pistes/">About Piste Difficulty</a></div> \
        </div> \
        ';

            this._map = map;
            this._container = document.createElement('div');
            this._container.className = 'fs-legend-control';
            this._container.innerHTML = fs_legend_control_html;
            return this._container;
        }
        onRemove() {
            this._container.parentNode.removeChild(this._container);
            this._map = undefined;
        }
    }

    map.addControl(new fs_legend_control(), "top-left");
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: If you share a complete source, the barrier to help you here goes way, way down. As it is, only people familiar with mapbox or willing to spend a lot of time becoming so can help you, even though this has a high likelihood of not being more than an HTML/CSS/JS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it was as simple as [this].  While the mobile version in developer tools in Chrome displayed correct, it did not display correctly on my mobile.  I deleted chrome on my cell and reinstalled it and it worked.  This is the solution also used in the link provided.  No idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

> I deleted chrome on my cell and reinstalled it and it worked

One side effect of that reinstallation would be to benefit from a cleared cache, allowing the browser to fetch the latest version of the webpage and its associated files.

And that can also include the latest version, updating it to a newer version where such bugs were fixed.

Check also if there was any extension in your previous Chrome installation which have been removed during that reinstallation process: those could have  interfered with the webpage rendering.

Answer (score -2):

When your Mapbox legend is working on desktop and tablet but not on mobile devices, there are a few potential issues to consider and steps you can take to troubleshoot and fix the problem:

Responsive CSS: Ensure that your CSS styles are responsive and mobile-friendly. Check if there are specific styles applied to the legend that might be causing layout issues on smaller screens. Use media queries to adjust styles for different screen sizes.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Mobile styles for the legend */
}
```

Viewport Settings: Verify the meta viewport tag in the  section of your HTML. Make sure it's properly configured to ensure the correct rendering of the web page on mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Javascript Errors: Check your browser's developer console for any JavaScript errors specific to mobile devices. These errors might be causing the legend not to render properly. Addressing these errors can resolve the issue.

Browser Compatibility: Test the map and legend on multiple mobile browsers (such as Chrome, Safari, Firefox) to see if the issue persists across different platforms. Sometimes, browser-specific CSS or JavaScript inconsistencies can cause problems.

Mapbox Libraries: Ensure that you are using the latest version of the Mapbox JavaScript library. Older versions might have compatibility issues with certain mobile devices. Update the library to the latest version to benefit from bug fixes and improvements.

Legend Markup: Double-check the HTML markup and CSS styles for the legend. It's possible that the legend elements are not structured properly for mobile devices. Simplify the legend design if needed, focusing on basic HTML and CSS to ensure compatibility.

By addressing these points and testing your application on various mobile devices and browsers, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue causing the Mapbox legend not to display correctly on mobile devices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see read, [Current policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).  We do hope you'll stick around and become a valued member of the community by posting your own quality questions and answers in the future - Thanks!